# Vagrant and Chef bafflement. It's not doing what I think it should

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have the Opscode php cookbook, which works fine... almost.
I made modifications to the php.ini.erb file, but that file is not being copied as instructed in the script. I am using an ubutnu base box, so I modified `php/templates/ubuntu/php.ini.erb` and recreated the Vagrant box. The changes I made to the template file don't end up in the php.ini file used by the system; it just uses a completely default php.ini.

Also, I'd like to install xdebug. So I made my own recipe, `php/recipes/module_xdebug.rb`, that contains this:

```
template "/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini" do
  source "xdebug.ini.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0644
  notifies :restart, resources("service[apache2]"), :delayed
end
```

...and then added the following to the bottom of the `php/metadata.rb` file:

```
recipe "php::module_xdebug", "Install the php5-xdebug package"
```

...and the file `php/templates/*/xdebug.ini.erb` contains:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
```

I put this file in all the template directories. Yet when I provision, the file isn't copied.

Also, I am trying to download and extract Zend Framework. To do this, I am cheating a little by adding some code to foot of the `php/recipes/source.rb` file:

```
remote_file "/tmp/ZendFramework-1.12.3.tar.gz" do
  source "https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.12.3/ZendFramework-1.12.3.tar.gz"
  mode 0644
end

bash "Extract ZendFramework" do
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
  tar zxvf ZendFramework-1.12.3.tar.gz
  mv ZendFramework-1.12.3 /usr/share/php5
  EOH
end

directory "/usr/share/php5/ZendFramework-1.12.3" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
  recursive true
end
```

Which doesn't work, either, though I sort of expected that not to, as it is a complete hack and is probably full of mistakes.

So I am having to re-evaluate my quick-learning ability, as the only things I've tried to do differently than the vanilla install are these three things, and not one of them works. *pout*

Could anyone shed some light on my (probably many) fails?

Comment: What recipes you actually run? Show your Vagrantfile, particularly `chef.add_recipe` lines.

Comment: Maybe `VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG vagrant up` will help you out since it has verbose output. It seems like your run_list isn't correct, or the blocks aren't getting triggered for some reason. Could you post your Vagrantfile and perhaps some output from a non-verbose `vagrant up` regarding the run_list expansion.

Comment: Another possibility is that you're using the wrong Vagrant box. The 'default' ones from http://www.vagrantbox.es/ don't necessarily have a version of Chef corresponding to your version installed. You should prefer [Opscode's Bento](https://github.com/opscode/bento)

Comment: sidenote: @Rob3 if you decide to edit can you make it much more substantial than you did on this question? Thanks.